# Passing an Array as an Argument Into SetTimeout Callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, settimeout

I've been trying for two days now to pass an array into a setTimeout callback.

I've been looking all over the internet, and I've read maybe 10 different StackOverflow questions with all their answers. I must be missing something because after trying all of these different things it still doesn't work. Here is where I stand right now:

```
function testing(pixels){    

        return function(){
          for(i=0; i<pixels.length;i++){
                a = pixels[i][0];
                b = pixels[i][1];
                c = pixels[i][2];
                d = pixels[i][3];
                box = pixels[i][5];
                done = pixels[i][6];


                color_to_draw = done ? box.color:active_color;
                ctx.fillRect(a,b,c,d);        
                ctx2.clearRect(box.x-1,box.y-1,box.w,box.h);
                draw_colored_box(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h, color_to_draw, box.alpha, true, ctx2);
            }
        };

}

function ias(pixel_batch){
  var color_to_draw; 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    var a, b, c, d, e, box, done, i;


        setTimeout(testing(pixel_batch),pixel_batch[0][4]);
}
```

I've gotten out of all the different solutions I found that my method here *should* work. I am clearly doing something wrong, as it DOES NOT work.

The problem is that, in the function `ias()`, `pixel_batch.length` is equal to 3, or however many items get put into that array, even in the function `testing()`, `pixels.length` is the correct value, but inside the function RETURNED by testing, pixels.length` is equal to 0...

Originally, this is what I had tried:

```
function ias(pixel_batch){
  var color_to_draw; 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    var a, b, c, d, e, box, done, i;


        setTimeout((function(pixels){
            console.log(pixels.length);

            return function(){

              for(i=0; i<pixels.length;i++){
                    a = pixels[i][0];
                    b = pixels[i][1];
                    c = pixels[i][2];
                    d = pixels[i][3];
                    box = pixels[i][5];
                    done = pixels[i][6];


                    color_to_draw = done ? box.color:active_color;
                    ctx.fillRect(a,b,c,d);        
                    ctx2.clearRect(box.x-1,box.y-1,box.w,box.h);
                    draw_colored_box(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h, color_to_draw, box.alpha, true, ctx2);
                }
            };
        })(pixel_batch),pixel_batch[0][4]);
}
```

As believe it does not need to be done through an externally defined function, but at this point I've started trying anything/everything.

How can I get pixel_batch (the parameter passed to `ias()`) into the callback for setTimeout?

**[EDIT/UPDATE]**
Here is the code that actually CALLS `ias()`:

```
function redraw_boxes(){

    //This loop simply draws the active boxes again, on top of the previous set.
    //At this point in time there is no need to clear the canvas at all.
    var i; var i2; var box;
    var temp_pixelation_array = pixelation_array.slice(0);
    var x_mod; var y_mod; 
    var random_array_key;
    var max_runs;
    var the_pixel_batch = [];
    var num_pixels_per_batch = 3;
    var speed_to_pixelate = 3;
    var done;
    var temptimer=0;
    var timers = [];
    for(i=0;i<newly_acquired_boxes.length;i++){    
    temptimer=0;

    temp_pixelation_array = pixelation_array.slice(0);
        max_runs = temp_pixelation_array.length;
            box = boxes[newly_acquired_boxes[i].column][newly_acquired_boxes[i].row];

        for(i2 = 0; i2<max_runs;i2++){

           random_array_key = ~~((Math.random()*temp_pixelation_array.length));

            x_mod = temp_pixelation_array[random_array_key][0];
            y_mod = temp_pixelation_array[random_array_key][1];
            temp_pixelation_array.splice(random_array_key,1);

            done = i2<max_runs-1 ? true:true ; 
            the_pixel_batch.push([box.x+x_mod, box.y+y_mod, particle_size, particle_size,temptimer,box,done]);
            if(the_pixel_batch.length>= num_pixels_per_batch){                
                ias(the_pixel_batch);
                the_pixel_batch.length = 0;
                temptimer += num_pixels_per_batch*speed_to_pixelate;
            }




        }






    }
    newly_acquired_boxes.length=0;


}
```

**[2 EDIT/UPDATE 2]**

I wish I could accept all your answers, as you were all technically right. It's my fault for not giving you the right information to begin with. I up voted everyone because you all deserved the answer, you just couldn't give it to me with the information provided.

Comment: At a very quick first glance, your approach seems sound at least

Comment: I think we'd need to see some data so we can test. I don't really see why you're invoking a function that returns a function in the first place. There's only one `setTimeout` being invoked in `ias`, so the callback has exclusive access to the values of the variables for that function invocation.

Comment: Breaking down your function into it's basic parts, it seems to work:  http://jsfiddle.net/pxaXq/

Comment: I'm only using the function that returns a function because I've been driven to try everything. Originally I just defined the function inside the setTimeout

Comment: @JonathonG: Is there *anything* left out of this function? Or does any other code have access to the `pixels` Array that could clear it before the `setTimeout` happens. There's something we're missing here.

Comment: I just added the code that calls the ias() function. It does in fact clear the original the_pixels_array before the setTimeout runs, however, I thought that in passing the_pixels_array into ias, that wouldn't matteR?

Comment: @JonathonG: Found it. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
ias(the_pixel_batch);
the_pixel_batch.length = 0;
```

You're clearing the Array before the `setTimeout` runs.

---

You should do:

```
pixel_batch.length = 0;
```

...in the `setTimeout` callback.

```
function ias(pixel_batch) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";

    setTimeout(function () {
        var color_to_draw, a, b, c, d, e, box, done, i;

        for (i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            a = pixels[i][0];
            b = pixels[i][1];
            c = pixels[i][2];
            d = pixels[i][3];
            box = pixels[i][5];
            done = pixels[i][6];

            color_to_draw = done ? box.color : active_color;
            ctx.fillRect(a, b, c, d);
            ctx2.clearRect(box.x - 1, box.y - 1, box.w, box.h);
            draw_colored_box(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h, color_to_draw, box.alpha, true, ctx2);
        }
        pixel_batch.length = 0; // <<--- RIGHT HERE
    }, pixel_batch[0][4]);
}
```

Comment: I thought it was being copied to the varialbe `pixel_batch` inside the `ias()` function, that's why I assumed this wasn't the problem.

Comment: I can't believe that I have already had this problem once, and now I have it again. the solution is to do `pixel_batch = pixel_batch.slice(0);` at the beginning of ias()......

Comment: @JonathonG: Yes, to make a shallow copy, you'd need `.slice()`, or just skip the slice, and clear the Array in the callback. But yeah, it's a pointer to the same array that is passed to the function.

Comment: I can't clear the array in the callback because the ias function gets run anywhere from 30 to 300 times before the first setTimeout even executes.

Comment: and each time the setTimeout callback runs, it needs to have 3 different pixels in the array. I suppose I could use some kind of offset passed in to modify `i`, but is there any disadvantage to using the `slice(0)` method?

Comment: @JonathonG: But is it being passed the same Array some of the time? If not, then it really shouldn't matter. Each `pixel_batch` parameter will be unique to each invocation of `ias()`. I assume it is a different Array every time since you were clearing the original.

Comment: ...the disadvantage to slice is just performance. I was mostly just curious as to the reason for the approach. Working code is first priority of course. :)

Comment: Well I did this whole pixel_batch thing to try and improve performance. Chrome handles this brilliantly but firefox takes a big hit. It looks like it wasn't the sheer number of setTimeouts that is causing the problem though, firefox just can't handle the number of fillRects.... I wish I could figure some way around having to use so many

Comment: @JonathonG: Yeah, wish I could help you there.

Answer (score 2):

Here a good article explaining how to do this: https://gullan.org.uk/passing-parameters-function-settimeout

Here is the conclusion : `setTimeout(function(){myFunction(parameter)}, myTimeout);`

Comment: i've tried this, to no avail. for some reason the array being passed in still has 0 length when I try to access it inside the callback function

Comment: I think the code is calling a function returned by testing(), so calling testing(...) directly in the setTimeout (rather than in a closure) is correct.

Comment: Your anonymous function is failing to close on the argument - when setTimeout actually applies your function, it has no defined variable pixels in its scope. David's answer sums up what my response was going to be, without going into the details of other approaches to fixing it.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni: It has the formal parameter `pixels`, no? `setTimeout((function(pixels){`

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni: There's no reason to believe it wouldn't close on it, other than the issue. That is to say, it *should* work. There's little difference between a variable and a formal parameter with respect to closure/scoping.

Comment: And the culprit is revealed in comments on the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on David's answer: I think what you may want is something like this:

```
function draw () {
      for(i=0; i<pixels.length;i++){
            a = pixels[i][0];
            b = pixels[i][1];
            c = pixels[i][2];
            d = pixels[i][3];
            box = pixels[i][5];
            done = pixels[i][6];


            color_to_draw = done ? box.color:active_color;
            ctx.fillRect(a,b,c,d);        
            ctx2.clearRect(box.x-1,box.y-1,box.w,box.h);
            draw_colored_box(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h, color_to_draw, box.alpha, true, ctx2);
        }
    }

function ias(pixel_batch){
  var color_to_draw; 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    var a, b, c, d, e, box, done, i;
    setTimeout(function () {draw(pixel_batch)},pixel_batch[0][4]);
}
```

There is no need for a function that returns a function, you can just use a closure to call the function directly.

Comment: Either this, or closing on the argument to the function by creating an in-scope copy as in my answer, should both work.

Comment: Then it seems like the problem must be somewhere else. Would it matter that the function that calls `ias(the_pixel_batch)` resets `the_pixel_batch[]` to 0 length after making the call?

Comment: Yes, because even my copy strategy was only copying the reference not copying the array.

Answer (score 1):

Are you modifying the `pixel_batch` array *after* calling `ias()` but *before* the timeout has executed? If so, you could pass a copy of the array:

```
setTimeout(testing(pixel_batch.slice(0)),pixel_batch[0][4]);
```

(Noting that [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) only makes a one-level deep copy of the array...)